# How to merge list of dict with same keys?

Tags: list, dictionary, merge, key

I have a list:

```py
list=[{'Query': 'documents'}, {'entity': 'a'}, {'value': 'b'}, {'entity': 'c'}, {'value': 'd'}, {'records':21}]
```

I want following o/p:

```py
d={'Query': ['documents'],'entity': ['a','c'],'value': ['b','d'],'records':[21]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code :

```
list=[{'Query': 'documents'}, {'entity': 'a'}, {'value': 'b'}, {'entity': 'c'}, {'value': 'd'}, {'records':21}]
d={}
for i in list :
    for j,k in i.items():
        l = []
        if j in d:
            l = d[j]
            l.append(k)
            d[j] = l
        else:
            l.append(str(k))
            d[j]=l
print(d)
```

output:

```
{'records': ['21'], 'value': ['b', 'd'], 'entity': ['a', 'c'], 'Query': ['documents']}
```